# IPython Notebook (Jupyter) Bash Kernel raising FileNotFoundError with Python3

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Recently upgraded to Anaconda Python3 but now when I try to launch a new notebook with the bash kernel I get the below traceback indicating that it is looking still for my previous python interpreter. Not sure how this can be updated to point to my new python in anaconda3 folder. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[E 10:40:58.086 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/base/handlers.py", line 365, in wrapper
            result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 53, in post
            model = sm.create_session(path=path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 66, in create_session
            kernel_name=kernel_name)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 84, in start_kernel
            kernel_name=kernel_name, **kwargs)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/multikernelmanager.py", line 112, in start_kernel
            km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
            **kw)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/manager.py", line 189, in _launch_kernel
            return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/launcher.py", line 213, in launch_kernel
            proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
            restore_signals, start_new_session)
          File "/ebs/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
            raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
        FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/anaconda/bin/python'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a symbolic link to achieve this:

`ln -s /path/to/old/binary /path/to/new/binary`

If you receive an insufficient permissions error, prepend `sudo` to the command.

In your case, you should symlink `/root/anaconda/bin/python` to the binary in your anaconda folder.